# Is my proof here correct (real analysis - continuity)?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification, continuity

This is exercise 4.3.9 from Stephen Abbott's *Understanding Analysis*:

> Assume $h : R → R$ is continuous on $R$ and let $K =
>  \left\{x\::\:h\left(x\right)=0\right\}.$ Show that $K$ is a closed set

I'm not sure whether my proof is correct and logically sound, so would be glad to hear reviews from those with more experience. It may be a bit verbose since I don't have much background in this. Here goes:

> Let $k\in \mathbb{R}$ be a limit point of the set $K$.
>
> $h$ is continuous on all of $R$, so it is in particular continuous at
> the point $k$, so for every $ɛ>0$ there exists a certain $δ>0$ such
> that whenever $\left|x-k\right|<δ$ (and $x\in \mathbb{R}$), it follows
> that $\left|h\left(x\right)-h\left(k\right)\right|<\:ε$.
>
> Since $k$ is a limit point of the set $K$, every $δ$-neighborhood of
> it contains a certain $x_0\in K$, so that for every $ɛ>0$, it follows
> in particular that:
>
> $$\left|h\left(x_0\right)-h\left(k\right)\right|<\:ε$$ $x_0\in K$ and
> thus $h\left(x_0\right)=0$, therefore, for every $ɛ>0$:
> $$\left|h\left(k\right)\right|<ɛ$$ Assuming by contradiction that that
> $h\left(k\right)>0$ and plugging $ɛ=h\left(k\right)$ yields:
> $$\left|h\left(k\right)\right|<h\left(k\right)\:→\:h\left(k\right)\:<\:h\left(k\right)\:→\:contradiction$$
> Likewise, assuming that $h\left(k\right)<0$ and plugging
> $ɛ\:=\:-h\left(k\right)$:
> $$\left|h\left(k\right)\right|<-h\left(k\right)\:→\:-h\left(k\right)<-h\left(k\right)\:→\:contradiction$$
>
> Thus $h\left(k\right)=0$, and $k\in K$, so $K$ is a closed set.

Thank you!

Comment: Once you show Abs[h(k)]<epsilon, you immediately know it equals zero, and is thus in K.

Comment: Note that $K=h^{-1}(\{0\})$ is the preimage of a closed set under a continuous map and hence closed.